# Numerical differences between manually computed gradient and PyTorch chain rule

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I am computing the gradient myself manually using formulas for this very simple linear network with a MSE loss.

I then compare with the gradient that is computed by PyTorch and use the `allclose` function from PyTorch to check that the gradients are correctly computed by PyTorch (i.e. the relative difference between the manually computed gradients and pytorch is small enough).
All the tests should pass as the formulas are correct. But for some seeds it just doesn't.

So obviously PyTorch isn't doing anything wrong but as the formulas are correct it must comes from some numerical instabilities issues in the formulas.

```
import torch

class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)


    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()

for i in range(0, 1000):
    torch.manual_seed(i)
    X = torch.randn(100, 10)
    y = torch.randn(100, 1)





    model=Network()
    model.train()
    optimizer=torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=1.)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = loss(model(X), y)
    output.backward()

    torch_grads=[]
    for p in model.parameters():
        torch_grads.append(p.grad.detach().data)



    #df/dW = (-2X.T*y+2*X.T*b+2*X.T*X*W)/nsamples 
    #df/db = (2*b-2*y+2*W.T*X.T).mean() (the mean comes from implicit broadcasting of b)

    theory_grad_w = (-2 * torch.matmul(X.t(), y)
                     +2 * torch.matmul(torch.t(X), torch.ones((X.shape[0], 1)))* list(model.parameters())[1]
                     +2 * torch.matmul(torch.matmul(X.t(), X), list(model.parameters())[0].t())
                     ) / float(X.shape[0])

    theory_grad_w = theory_grad_w.t()


    theory_grad_b = torch.mean(2 * list(model.parameters())[1]- 2 * y+ 2 * torch.matmul((list(model.parameters())[0]), torch.t(X)))

    theory_grads = [theory_grad_w, theory_grad_b]

    b=all([torch.allclose(u, d) for u, d in zip(torch_grads, theory_grads)])
    if not(b):

      print("i=%s, pass=%s"%(i, b))
```

What are the sources of the observed numerical instabilities and how to deal with them so that tests would pass all the time. Is it just a matter of ordering the operations differently ?

Comment: Try instead of `allclose()` use `np.testing.assert_almost_equal()` with smaller `decimal`. Maybe the difference is not that significant.

Comment: I have to increase `a_tol` by a factor of 100 if I want the tests to pass so no it is not a solution for me.

Comment: (btw `np` has also an `allclose` function where you can play with the parameters)